# Issue Loading Assembly in PowerShell with AssemblyConfigurationEntry

Tags: c#, powershell

I am running into issues loading an assembly into a PowerShell Runspace within a .net console application.

When running the application, I get the following error: "Cannot find type [Test.Libary.TestClass]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded."

I tried installing the assembly into the GAC, but it didn't seem to make any difference. I couldn't seem to find very much documentation on the AssemblyConfigurationEntry class, so any help is appreciated.

Console Application:

```
namespace PowerShellHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string assemblyPath = Path.GetFullPath("Test.Library.dll");

            RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

            var libraryAssembly = new AssemblyConfigurationEntry("Test.Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d7ac3058027aaf63", assemblyPath);
        config.Assemblies.Append(libraryAssembly);

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);
            runspace.Open();

            PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();
            shell.Runspace = runspace;

            shell.AddCommand("New-Object");
            shell.AddParameter("TypeName", "Test.Libary.TestClass");

            ICollection<PSObject> output = shell.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Test.Library.dll:

```
namespace Test.Library
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string TestProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `Add-Type` from script to accomplish this.

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create(); 

shell.AddScript(@"
Add-Type -AssemblyName Test.Library

$myObj = New-Object Test.Library.TestClass
$myObj.TestProperty = 'foo'
$myObj.TestPropery
"); 

ICollection<PSObject> output = shell.Invoke();
```

This should work if your DLL is in the GAC.  Otherwise, when calling `Add-Type` instead of `-AssemblyName Test.Library`, you would instead need to use `-Path c:\path\to\Test.Library.dll`

Comment: I tried my code on other computers and it worked just fine. Your is also a good workaround. Thanks for the tip.